# It's possible create Core ML models

Tags: swift, xcode, coreml

I'd like to know if it's possible create core ml models for xcode, my app needs recognize many different species in real time, so I need to create a custom model
I'm still begginer so please explain me step by step, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, for that you could use Caffe, Keras, turi or other libraries to generate trained models and then using Core ML python tool you can convert it to .mlmodel to use in xcode.
Also I will suggest to you to read this article :
http://www.reza.codes/2017-07-29/how-to-train-your-own-dataset-for-coreml/

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

YES - you can train your own model and *then* import it into CoreML. But NO - you cannot do any training once the model has been imported. (That will require an app update.)

Here's a few good links to get you started:

- A [repo](https://github.com/hollance/YOLO-CoreML-MPSNNGraph) and a [detailed article](http://machinethink.net/blog/yolo-coreml-versus-mps-graph/) that explains how to take a trained YOLO model and import it into CoreML.
- A very detailed [article](http://www.reza.codes/2017-07-29/how-to-train-your-own-dataset-for-coreml/) (with screenshots) of how to *"train a Caffe model using DIGITS on an EC2 g2.2xlarge instance, convert it into a CoreML model using Apple’s coremltools and integrate it into an iOS app"*.

I haven't gone completely through this last link yet, but from what I've done with the former one and other learning projects, it looks like the best (read: most extensive) "intro to training a Machine Learning model" you can find.

Remember, once you've imported your trained model into CoreML, the only way to update it - at least for now in iOS 11 - is to *reimport* the model, meaning an app update.

EDIT: In the comments, @MatthijsHollemans (who BTW is the author of those first two links and I recommend reading other articles on his [blog](http://machinethink.net/blog/)) points out a way to update the model *without* the need for an app update.

Comment: You can also download a new version of the .mlmodel file and compile it from inside the app, so then you don't have to make a new app update.

Comment: I did not know that! Thanks. I'll edit my answer.